# pyqt5 - Implementing a custom Horizontal ScrollBar for Qtextbrowser

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser, qscrollbar

I am making a pyqt widget to show bigger log files (1GB+). I will load them on demand. I have a Qtextbrowser in which I will read first N lines and after scrolling then i will load further. I don't want to use internal scrollbars of Qtetxbrowse as I have a separate lineNumber widget as well. hence I want to implement a custom vertical and hoxizontal scrollBar which will work as internal scrllbars. I have done vertical scrollBar implemeentation. I am facing follwoing issue while implementing Horzontal scrollBar

- Clicking on side of scrollbar doesn't scroll one character, instead it take 4-5 click to pass one character.
- Scrolling is too much slow with it
- Size(length) of horizontal scroll is not same as internal Horizontal scrollbar

[image]

```py
class MyQTextBrowser(QTextBrowser):
    resized = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def setVerticalScrollBar(self,obj):
        self.VerticalScrollBar = obj

    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.resized.emit()
    
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self.VerticalScrollBar.wheelEvent(event)
        super().wheelEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        self.VerticalScrollBar.keyPressEvent(event)
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
    

class LazyQTextBrowser(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__initUi()

    def __initUi(self):
        self.textBrowser = MyQTextBrowser(self)
        self.textBrowser.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textBrowser.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.vertical_scrollbar = QScrollBar(self)
        self.horizontal_scrollbar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal,self)

        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textBrowser.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBar(self.vertical_scrollbar)
        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBar2(self.horizontal_scrollbar)    

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text_edit_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        text_edit_layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        text_edit_layout.addWidget(self.vertical_scrollbar)
        main_layout.addLayout(text_edit_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.horizontal_scrollbar)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.textBrowser.resized.connect(self.textBrowserResized)
        self.vertical_scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(self.textBrowser.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.horizontal_scrollbar.valueChanged.connect(lambda x : self.refreshData())
        self.horizontal_scrollbar.setVisible(False)

    def refreshData(self):
        self.textBrowser.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontal_scrollbar.value())
        internal_slider_length = self.textBrowser.horizontalScrollBar().maximum()
        if internal_slider_length > 0:
            self.horizontal_scrollbar.setVisible(True)
            self.horizontal_scrollbar.setRange(0, internal_slider_length)
            # Slider height
            internal_slider_height = self.textBrowser.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()
            self.horizontal_scrollbar.setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:horizontal { height: " + str(internal_slider_height + 2) + "px; }")
            # Slider length
            self.horizontal_scrollbar.setPageStep(internal_slider_length) 
        else:
            self.horizontal_scrollbar.setVisible(False)
```

Comment: I'd start by replacing the viewer with QPlainTextEdit, which is specifically intended for large files and much faster than QTextEdit (and using a QTextBrowser makes no sense, since it has a very different purpose).

Comment: Hi musicamante, I have html format data because I need to show colored differenec like vimdiff utility, hence I t is need to load html data so Qtextbrowser is necessary here

Comment: Unless you need to provide internal navigation between different content (which I doubt), no, it isn't, and you should at least use QTextEdit, because QTextBrowser is just an extended QTextEdit class that provides hypertext navigation. And if you're using HTML just because you need different colors, you *can* use QPlainTextEdit nonetheless, you just need to access it's [`document()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document): `self.document().setHtml(<HTML content>)`.